# How to define default value for nconf globaly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, global, nconf

I'm trying to put my development project live. So to handle config I'll use [nconf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nconf).

I have defined on heroku my config var :

```
NODE_ENV: production
```

And I have a config object on dev:

```
config = {
  NODE_ENV: development
}
```

On the app.js file, I require nconf and I configure the priority order to args, env vars, and finally default config object (and it's work):

```
var nconf = require('nconf');
nconf.argv()
 .env()
 .defaults(config);
console.log(nconf.get('NODE_ENV')); // development || production
```

But now I try to use nconf on other file, or lib (required after the previous lines) and it didn't work.
I have to copy/past the priority order on each file to configure my default config.

Do I have a solution to define this only one time, and re-use it on each file/lib/controller...

Thank

Comment: How about setting `process.env.node_env`  as it will be accessible across all `*.js` files in node..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The process object is a global object and can be accessed from anywhere.
>
> Refer https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process

Comment: Yeah, but `process.env.node_env` isn't udate by my config object. 
So on development, `process.env.NODE_ENV === undefined`

Comment: Yes, I am suggesting you to set this variable and use its value in your `conf` file like `config = {
  NODE_ENV: process.env.node_env || 'development'
}`

Comment: Humm, I see.. Thanks!

Comment: **Happy coding** *Node is fun*